# Jupyter asynchronously interact with running cell

Tags: python, asynchronous, jupyter-notebook, ipython

Can I use asyncio in Python to release control to another Jupyter Cell?

For example, suppose I have a Jupyter cell such

```
x = 'foo'
for i in range(1_000_000):
    long_computation()
    print(x)
```

and I run it. While it is running, I decide I want to change `x='bar'`, but I don't want to stop the loop. Ideally, I would like to go to the next cell, type `x = 'bar'` and run it, and have the loop immediately pick up this change and start printing out 'bar' without loosing it's place. Obviously, what happens now is that it just adds this cell to the queue to be executed once the loop finishes.

Is there any way for me to add some sort of `await` statement which would make this possible?

Answer (score 0):

To clarify your question:

1. If you mean you want to run these two cells(loop cell and change x cell) one by one. That's possible and you just need to run the second cell, and it will be executed after the first one immediately.
2. If you mean you want to run the second cell while the first cell is running. That's impossible.

Comment: I meant the second.